# Magento 2 : After creating "Conditions Model and Fieldset in custom module, How to validate that condition on frontend to showing specific block?

Tags: magento2, module, conditions-serialized, salerule

I have just followed the below tutorial to create condition fieldset and model in the custom module.

https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/

Also, it's working perfect, see below screenshot:

[image]

Now, please let me know how I can apply this condition on the frontend area to show a specific block?

Please share your view on this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you get it fixed how to fetch on frontend ?